# Loguru stops logging flask exceptions in production

Tags: python, flask

I am using Loguru to handle the logging in my flask rest api. When testing the app locally it logs exactly as expected. When I deploy my app to my linux server running apache the logging stops. I can run the app manually on the server using `python app.py` and the logging works again but that just spins up the development server.

```py
from flask import Flask
from loguru import logger
import logging
import os


class InterceptHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        # Retrieve context where the logging call occurred, this happens to be in the 6th frame upward
        logger_opt = logger.opt(depth=6, exception=record.exc_info)
        logger_opt.log(record.levelno, record.getMessage())


# create the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)

logger.add(
    'logs/events.log',
    level='DEBUG',
    format='{time} {level} {message}',
    backtrace=True,
    rotation='5 MB',
    retention=9
)

app.logger.addHandler(InterceptHandler())
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[InterceptHandler()], level=20)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the issue. By default using the werkzeug dev server it was using the logs/events.log file. When I deployed the application to the apache server, it rerouted the logs that would have been placed here and put them in with the apache server logs